# Не получается интегрировать Perfect many

Tags: платежи

Делаю платежную форму Перфект мани на сайте. Сделал по инструкции, сама оплата работает, но когда после успешной оплаты нас перекидывает назад на сайт, хешь от сервера не приходит для проверки.

форма

```
<form action="https://perfectmoney.com/api/step1.asp" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_ACCOUNT" value="UХХХХХХХХ">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_NAME" value="Тест имя">
<input type="text" name="PAYMENT_ID" value=""><BR>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_UNITS" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="STATUS_URL" value="https://хххххх/status/">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL" value="https://хххххх/succes/">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL" value="https://хххххх/error/">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="SUGGESTED_MEMO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BAGGAGE_FIELDS" value="id">
<input type="submit" name="PAYMENT_METHOD" value="Pay Now!">
</form>
```

Когда, после успешной оплаты, перекидывает на страницу /succes/ все переменные кроме $_POST['V2_HASH'] определяются верно, а $_POST['V2_HASH'] вместо кеша содержит вот такое значение - error_empty_phrase

пытался гуглить, но нечего не гуглиться и вот сижу и непонятно что делать.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: Очень полезный комментарий, нечего ответить по делу, так не флудите. У перефект мани никогда не было нормальной поддержки.